# ERROR 4078 (HY000) at line 167956: Illegal parameter data types uuid and int for operation '='

Tags: backup, mariadb, dump

I'm using this command to backup all of my MariaDB databases and gzip them all:

```
mariadb-dump -pPassword --all-databases --routines --events --single-transaction | gzip -c > dump.sql.gz
```

Then I copy that file to another server, and use this command to restore them all:

```
gzip -d dump.sql.gz
mariadb -pPassword < dump.sql
```

And I get this error:

> ERROR 4078 (HY000) at line 167956: Illegal parameter data types uuid and int for operation '='

Isn't this strange? I mean I have not changed anything. I just use the `mariadb-dump` and `maraidb` commands. Why should it not create a robust restoring script?

I'm using this version of MariaDB:

> MySQL version: 11.1.2-MariaDB-1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204 through PHP extension MySQLi

Comment: Show us the offending SQL statement.